# ComboBox EditValue Assignment will fire selectedValueChanged event?

Tags: c#, events, combobox, selectedvalue

I have the code below:
this.NameComboBox.EditValue = value;
I find when value is not empty, it will automatically fire the event:
NameComboBox_SelectedValueChanged

Acutally I replace the comboBox with my control in our project code, and due to my control doesn't have the selectedValueChanged event, so I use mycontrol_leave to replace this NameComboBox_SelectedValueChanged. All works fine but the only problem is the line of code "this.myControl.EditValue = value;" will not call mycontrol_leave automatically.

Shall I just add a condition after "this.NameComboBox.EditValue = value;":
if value is not null or empty string
  myControl_leave;

Thanks!

Comment: Metro? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fire the event mycontrol_leave in the setter of the property EditValue.